# Adding DATETIME() and Status column with xp_FileExist result

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add a two columns in addition to the results of `xp_FileExist`. Here's my T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @path varchar (100)
DECLARE @file varchar (100)
SET @file = '<location>\*.txt'
SET @path = 'dir /B ' + @file
EXEC xp_cmdshell  @path, NO_OUTPUT

CREATE TABLE FILEEXISTS (
        [NAME] VARCHAR (50) NULL)

INSERT into FILEEXISTS exec master..xp_cmdshell @path 

SELECT *
FROM FILEEXISTS
```

I tried to define columns in the "Create Table" section and add them after the `@path` but it throws an error every time saying something in the line of `too many parameters`. Any pointers?

Comment: [Are you looking for something like this ?](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1263/accessing-the-windows-file-system-from-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code to your question that *doesn't* work (that causes the error you are seeing).

Having said that, you probably want to modify the code you are using to something like:

```
DECLARE @path varchar (100);
DECLARE @file varchar (100);
SET @file = 'C:\temp\*.*';
SET @path = 'dir /B ' + @file;

DECLARE @FILEEXISTS TABLE(
        [NAME] VARCHAR (255) NULL
);

INSERT into @FILEEXISTS 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @path ;

SELECT *
FROM @FILEEXISTS;

DECLARE @table TABLE(
        [NAME] VARCHAR (255) NULL
        , somecol VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @table(NAME)
SELECT name
FROM @FILEEXISTS;

UPDATE @table SET somecol = 'test' /* add a 'WHERE' clause if necessary */;

SELECT *
FROM @table;
```

This uses a table-variable to store the results, and doesn't execute the unnecessary `xp_cmdshell` right after the `set @path=...` line.

The `@table` declaration (and other code) I added to the end allows you grab the results into `@fileexists`, then insert *those* results into `@table` and add the other columns as necessary.  `xp_cmdshell` returns a single column of results, one line for each line output by the command it runs.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver. This is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using xp_cmdshell instead use xp_fileexist.  It runs a variable to a parameter that you pass it, then you don't need to worry about adding columns to a table.  Just drop the values that you want into the table and off you go.